# "self.triggers is null" when trying to use trigger values in local-exec provisioner

Tags: terraform

I am trying to figure out why I am getting errors in my terraform output. I figured out that you cannot use `var.whatever` values in destroy-time provisioners, and that you are supposed to map any needed values to triggers instead, so I created a null_resource that looks like the below:

```
resource "null_resource" "upload-swagger" {
  triggers = {
    swagger_name         = "juice-shop-swagger"
    xc_password          = var.xc_password
    xc_p12_path          = var.xc_p12_path
    xc_api_url           = var.xc_api_url
    xc_namespace         = var.xc_namespace
    swaggerfile_location = var.swaggerfile_location
  }
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = <<EOT
      curl -sk --cert-type P12 \
        --cert ${self.triggers.xc_p12_path}:${self.triggers.xc_password} \
        -X PUT "${self.triggers.xc_api_url}/object_store/namespaces/${self.triggers.xc_namespace}/stored_objects/swagger/${self.triggers.swagger_name}" \
        -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
        -d '{
          "bytes_value": "$(base64 --wrap=0 ${self.triggers.swaggerfile_location})",
          "content_format": "yaml",
          "name": "${self.triggers.swagger_name}",
          "namespace": "${self.triggers.xc_namespace}",
          "object_type": "swagger"
        }'
      EOT
  }
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    when    = destroy
    command = <<EOT
      curl -sk --cert-type P12 \
        --cert ${self.triggers.xc_p12_path}:${self.triggers.xc_password} \
        -X DELETE "${self.triggers.xc_api_url}/object_store/namespaces/${self.triggers.xc_namespace}/stored_objects/swagger/${self.triggers.swagger_name}" \
        -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
        -d '{
          "name": "${self.triggers.swagger_name}",
          "namespace": "${self.triggers.xc_namespace}",
          "object_type": "swagger"
        }'
      EOT
  }
}
```

Upon `terraform apply`, I'm getting lots of errors in a form similar to the below:

```
Error: Attempt to get attribute from null value
│ 
│   on xc.tf line 128, in resource "null_resource" "upload-swagger":
│  128:         --cert ${self.triggers.xc_p12_path}:${self.triggers.xc_password} \
│     ├────────────────
│     │ self.triggers is null
│ 
│ This value is null, so it does not have any attributes.
```

What am I doing wrong in my invocation of `self.triggers`?

Comment: In this situation there is no real benefit to referencing `self.triggers` object versus `var` object, so you could always use that instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try linking to the `null_resource` object directly during apply and using `self` during destroy.

```
resource "null_resource" "null-test" {
  triggers = {
    trigger_name         = "trigger-test"
  }
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = <<EOT
      echo ${null_resource.null-test.triggers.trigger_name}
    EOT
  }
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    when = destroy
    command = <<EOT
      echo ${self.triggers.trigger_name}
    EOT
  }
}
```